# Code that runs in Virtual Device Manager but force closes on phone

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

```
package com.example.arduino;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private Button java;
 private SeekBar servo;
 byte srValue;


 private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    ListView listDevicesFound;
    Button btnScanDevice;
    TextView stateBluetooth;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnScanDevice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scandevice);

        stateBluetooth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bluetoothstate);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
        listDevicesFound = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.devicesfound);
        btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listDevicesFound.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);

        servo = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.servocontroller);

        CheckBlueToothState();

        btnScanDevice.setOnClickListener(btnScanDeviceOnClickListener);

        registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, 
          new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));


        servo.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

          OutputStream Device;

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                try{
                srValue = (byte)progress;
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                String temp = "r";
                byte bytes[] = temp.getBytes();

                try {
                    Device.write(bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Device.write(srValue);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }


    @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDestroy();
  unregisterReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver);
 }

 private void CheckBlueToothState(){
     if (bluetoothAdapter == null){
         stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth NOT support");
        }else{
         if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
          if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
           stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is currently in device discovery process.");
          }else{
           stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is Enabled.");
           btnScanDevice.setEnabled(true);
          }
         }else{
          stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is NOT Enabled!");
          Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
             startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
         }
        }
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener btnScanDeviceOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   btArrayAdapter.clear();
   bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
  }};

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
   CheckBlueToothState();
  }
 }

 private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String action = intent.getAction();
   if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
             BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
             btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
             btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
  }};


}
```

Alright This code compiles in the Virtual Device Manager But when i import it to my phone It crashes right away, I have been stuck for hours. how can it compile on eclipse but not on phone? I tried on many lower level Android os but still force closes every single time

```
    07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arduino/com.example.arduino.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity } from ProcessRecord{41864c40 6517:com.example.arduino/u0a10153} (pid=6517, uid=10153) requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity } from ProcessRecord{41864c40 6517:com.example.arduino/u0a10153} (pid=6517, uid=10153) requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1893)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1412)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.arduino.MainActivity.CheckBlueToothState(MainActivity.java:121)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.arduino.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)

07-23 21:53:40.204  6517  6517 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 11 more

07-23 21:53:40.214   661 12263 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.arduino/.MainActivity

07-23 21:53:40.324   661 12263 D dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1794K, 27% free 24899K/33868K, paused 77ms, total 78ms

07-23 21:53:40.824   661   676 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{416c36f0 u0 com.example.arduino/.MainActivity}

07-23 21:53:40.965   661   661 I ActivityManager: No longer want com.android.musicfx (pid 6218): empty #17

07-23 21:53:41.505  6517  6517 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 6517 SIG: 9

07-23 21:53:41.505   661  1293 I ActivityManager: Process com.example.arduino (pid 6517) has died.

07-23 21:53:41.525   661 22882 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41c3e618 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41c84818

07-23 21:53:42.086   873 12278 D dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6812K, 38% free 27836K/44836K, paused 60ms, total 60ms

07-23 21:53:42.146   873 12278 D dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 38K, 36% free 29069K/44836K, paused 34ms, total 34ms

07-23 21:53:42.146   873 12278 I dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 29.565MB for 1048592-byte allocation

07-23 21:53:42.206   873   885 D dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 35% free 30093K/45864K, paused 53ms, total 53ms

07-23 21:53:42.236   873 12278 D dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 35% free 30093K/45864K, paused 35ms, total 35ms

07-23 21:53:42.246   873 12278 I dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 31.344MB for 1865972-byte allocation

07-23 21:53:42.286   873   885 D dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 34% free 31914K/47688K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
```

Comment: It doesn't need to compile on the phone. You compile in eclipse and run it in an AVD or the phone. Now could you please calm down with the boldface and question marks?

Comment: Runs in Virtual Divice manager but force closes on phone

Comment: I thought that the code would hide the explanation I am new

Comment: Yes. We know that I just wanted to make it clear that there was no compiling going on the phone. Ever.

Comment: Because it's designed this way. Compile in Eclipse, run on AVD or the phone. Could you somehow get a stacktrace from the phone? And I must apologize, my first comment was rudely worded.

Comment: thats fine, I have a rooted phone, i use this app called AIED that shows  the stacktrace but toooo many processes to look at

Comment: We really need the stacktrace to help you./

Comment: ok is there a way you know that would be easy, i have a rooted phonw

Comment: OK i get it i'll post it here in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to declare the bluetooth permission in your app manifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Dude but when i export the app. the permissions revert back to its original state!!!! and i loose all the assigned permissions!

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="6" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

Comment: You must have both BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and BLUETOOTH permissions declared (if you really need BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission, check the android developer page http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#Permissions)

Comment: Got it work Thanks alot. I was working with the wrong xml file

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE
>   cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity } from
>   ProcessRecord{41864c40 6517:com.example.arduino/u0a10153} (pid=6517,
>   uid=10153) **requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH**

Have you added the permission for accessing the Bluetooth in the manifest?

Comment: I think so. It is checking for access for Bluetooth. If i dont how would i do it. i am completely stuck